Is BBO the same as NBBO?
I have read wikipedia pages about National best bid and offer (NBBO). It seems to me that in the US market, one stock can be traded on different markets, that's why NBBO is needs, it is an aggregated BBO.
I'm not sure whether I understand this correctly. I checked apple's official web page, it says: "Apple stock is traded on the NASDAQ Global Select Market under the ticker symbol AAPL." It seems that apple stock is ONLY traded on NASDAQ, then there is no need to aggregate apple stock prices. Does that mean for apple stock, BBO=NBBO?

BBO (Best Bid and Offer) reflects the best prices on a single exchange, like NASDAQ. NBBO (National Best Bid and Offer), however, aggregates the best prices across all U.S. trading venues.
Although Apple (AAPL) is listed on NASDAQ, it trades on multiple venues like NYSE and alternative trading systems. As a result, the NBBO for AAPL is calculated from the best bid and offer across all venues, not just NASDAQ.
